# Standalone replica sets mongodb

Tags: mongodb, replication

I need to create a standalone replica set in mongo. I followed the steps here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/

Everything worked as expected, but I was wondering how I could configure this in the mongodb.conf file so I didn't have to manually do these steps every time. Is something like this possible via the conf file? I know there is a `replSet` param that you can have in the conf file, but I wasn't sure how to specify which ports to use for the different replica sets. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the command line parameters you specify are settable in the configuration file - you can see how here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

Specifically, notice that you can set, port, replSet, and dbPath from the configuration file.

There is also a good article on Replica set configuration here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/

Comment: "On two distinct systems, start two new standalone mongod instances. For information on starting a standalone instance, see the installation tutorial specific to your environment." -- When they say on two distinct systems, that does me another box? I thought this standalone guide was to run multiple mongo instances on a single box for development testing.

Comment: Is the way to start multiple mongo instances by running `/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf` except with different conf files that specify different ports?

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly right, though obviously /etc/mongodb.conf is the 'system' config file, and you would want different paths for each of yours.  At the end of the day, you're going to deploy your replica sets on individual machines, as this is what gives you the benefits of a replica set.  This should only be for testing your environment.  There's no reason your development environment shouldn't be a single mongod (staging and production would be replSets).